# search a list in another list using Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, sublist

I am trying to write the sublist search algorithm using Python.

For reference : 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sublist-search-search-a-linked-list-in-another-list/

Here is my code:

```
def sublist(arr1,arr2):
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
if len(arr1) == 0:
    print('List1 Empty')
if len(arr2) == 0:
    print('List 2 Empty')
for j in range(0,len(arr2)):
    for i in range(0,len(arr1)):
        if arr1[i] != arr2[j]:
            break
        while arr1[i] == arr2 [j]:
            if i == len(arr1) - 1:
                return True
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
            if i == len(arr1):
                return False
        return False
```

I am sure this code can be optimized and reduce time complexity. Because of while loop, does the complexity increase than O(m*n)? Beginner student here

Comment: Are you sure this code works? Seems like you don't need the second for loop if you just make `i = 0` before each iteration.

Comment: @Yonlif You're right. The second for loop never actually needs to iterate since it traverses the supposed sublist so if the first index does not match there is no need to traverse the list further and it won't due to the first `if` having a `break` statement. All other code paths return so the loop will never be executed more than once. Essentially the `for` loop is just fancy way of resetting `i = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this works better:

```
def sublist(arr1,arr2):
  "This fuction checks if arr1 is a sublist of arr2."
  for i in range(len(arr2)):
    part=arr2[i:] # part is a list which all the elements from i to the end of arr2
    if len(part)<len(arr1):
      return False
    if arr1==part[:len(arr1)]: # if arr1 is in the beginning of part return True
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: Yes this works but you could save space by not using `part` and instead just performing the operations on `arr2` using `i`.

Comment: You do not need to specify both limits of a slice. `part=arr2[i:]` and `elif arr1 == part[:len(arr1)]` would suffice.

Comment: @MrDeal Using `part` saves time: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542474/should-i-store-a-calculation-in-a-variable-if-it-will-be-used-a-lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542474/should-i-store-a-calculation-in-a-variable-if-it-will-be-used-a-lot)

Answer (score 1):

The following compares the first portion of `arr2` to `arr1`, to determine if they are equal. If so, or any recursive call on some offset of `arr2` returns true, then return true. Otherwise, if at any point the sublist of the original `arr2` is shorter than `arr1`, return False.

```
def sublist(arr1, arr2):
    if len(arr2) < len(arr1):
        return False
    return arr1 == arr2[:len(arr1)] or sublist(arr1, arr2[1:])
```