# How do i find one list in another list with python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two lists:

`lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,3,2,5,6]`

`listb=[3,4,5]`

I want to find the first occurrence of the elements of listb in the order of listb in lista.

I have tried

```
print(lista.index(listb))
```

but it gives the error

```
ValueError: [3, 4, 5] is not in list
```

I have also tried

```
np.where(np.array(lista)==np.array(listb))
```

but it returns

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

What am I doing wrong?

The intended output with lista and listb should be 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [search a list in another list using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029591/search-a-list-in-another-list-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `list comprehension`:

```
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,3,2,5,6]
listb=[3,4,5]

[print(f"Index = {x}") for x in range(len(lista)) if lista[x:x+3] == listb]
```

Output:

```
Index = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need index position of your `listb` in `lista`.

**Code**

```
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,3,2,5,6]

listb=[3,4,5]

for i in listb:
    if i in lista:
        print (lista.index(i))
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`print([lista.index(n) for n in listb])`

Answer (score 0):

```
flag2 = False
for i in lista:
    if listb[0] == i:
        c = lista.index(i)
        k = c
        flag = True
        for j in range(len(listb)):
            if listb[j] != lista[c]:
                flag = False
                break
            c = c+1
        if flag:
            flag2 = True
            print(k)
            break
if not flag2:
    print('Does not exist')
```